# ajax response not success with rails respond to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#comment_form').on('click', '.button', function() {

      url = document.URL
      body = $(this).find('#comment_body').text()

      $.ajax(url, {
        method: 'post',
        data: body,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          alert("got success")
        },
        error: function(response) {
          debugger;
          alert("got an error")
        }
      });
  });
});
```

and the following controller code

```
  def create
      @comment = commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
      @comment.user = current_user

      respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
          format.json { render json: @comment }
        else
          format.json { render json: @comment.errors }
        end
      end
  end
```

Whenever I make this call from my client I get a error response from my server and I do not know why? It looks like I have followed exactly what is supposed to be done. Please help to return a successful response so i can update the dom with the comment.

Thank you.

Comment: I am gone bet it is a routing problem. What url are you sending it to?

Comment: BTW, you can get an exact server response with Firebug. It should clearly state what the error is.

Comment: What's the error message on the server?

Comment: What type of error is in the browser console? 422? 500?

Answer (score 0):

To start off, try with 'url' inside the hash:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'post',
  data: body,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    alert("got success")
}
```